# Should I show inheritence in Sequence Diagram

Tags: sequence-diagram

Do I need to show the different implementation of classes in a sequence diagram? I am trying to keep it simple.Therefore,should I hide different implementation in order to keep it generic? Or I should show a use case with one possible implementation or it depends? :)

[image]

Comment: No. A sequence digram is a set of exchanges between objects, capturing dynamic behaviour. Inheritance is a static, design, issue and does not belong on a sequence diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment already said: a SD does not tell anything about inheritance. This is a purely statical aspect which you can show in class diagrams.

As to whether show different implementations: it depends. Given you have multiple collaborations which realize a single use case (e.g. if you have multiple product lines or options in a product) you might wish to show the different behavior in different SD. But likely just only if there are variants between the different implementations. If you have a general path you would show that only once and reference it from the other collaborations.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of inheritance doesn't totally lie in the sequence diagram.
The sequence diagram shows object life line and objects used according to your project.
If you want inheritance, you should use class diagram, aggregation and composition to show it.